# Concatenate string in JSON field and truncate last characters

Tags: json, bash, jq

I want to add a string (which is a script argument - in this case "tenant-lta") in JSON objects to a value in field "alertruleindexpattern" and truncate `-*` or `*` if it is at the end of the string. Could someone help me with this?

JSON Object:

```
{
  "_index": ".alertrules",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "tenant-lta_Windows_Admin_task_as_user",
  "_score": 0.07554413,
  "_source": {
    "alertrulemethoddata": "",
    "alertruleimportance": 50,
    "alertruletype": "any",
    "alertrule_any": "filter:\n - query_string:\n     query: \"event_id:4732 AND NOT user.role:admin\"",
    "alertrulemethodusers": [],
    "alertrulemethod": "none",
    "alertruleindexpattern": "winlogbeat-*",
    "alertruleplaybooks": [],
    "alertrulefilename": "tenant-lta_Windows_Admin_task_as_user",
    "alertrulename": "tenant-lta-Windows - Admin task as user",
    "enable": "N",
    "selectedroles": [
      "tenant-lta"
    ],
    "alertruleriskkeyaggregation": "MAX",
    "authenticator": "index",
    "alertruleriskkey": "",
    "changed": false
  }
}
```

Desired output in field `alertruleindexpattern`:

```
{
    "alertruleindexpattern": "tenant-lta-winlogbeat",
    
}
```

My attempts:

```
ruleindexpattern=`echo "$i" | jq '._source.alertruleindexpattern' | pcregrep -o1 '"(.*?)[-]?\*"$'`
sed -i 's/\"alertruleindexpattern\":\"'$ruleindexpattern'\"/\"alertruleindexpattern\":\"'$tenantname'-'$ruleindexpattern'\"/g' $alert_file
```

Comment: I only pasted the field I want to change as I described. The original object is mentioned after "JSON Object:".
I edited the post to show my attempts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
echo "$json" | 
  jq --arg prefix tenant-lta- \
    '{alertruleindexpattern: ($prefix + (._source.alertruleindexpattern | match("(.*?)(?=-\\*$|$)").captures[0].string))}'
```

Comment: This helps a lot, but now I wonder how to overwrite this values in a file.

Comment: Use the [update assignment](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Assignment), peak is using in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could and probably should perform the update using jq without complicating things using other programs as well.

Assuming an invocation of jq using `—-argson tenantname` appropriately, the jq filter would be along these lines:

```
._source.alertruleindexpattern 
|= $tenantname + "-" + sub("-?[*]$";"")
```

Comment: Could you elaborate? I am a total newbie in jq.